# How to connect angular10 post api with slim 4 php?

Tags: php, angular, api, slim, slim-4

My angular application runs on http://localhost:4200/ and my Slim4 application runs on localhost:8080. When I try to integrate APIS between angular and slim, GET API works fine, but the POST API does not. I get the below CORS error,

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/admin/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

[image: API]

My angular request 'content-type' is 'applictaion/json'. Please find the slim4 response header below,

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Application\ResponseEmitter;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Slim\ResponseEmitter as SlimResponseEmitter;

class ResponseEmitter extends SlimResponseEmitter
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function emit(ResponseInterface $response): void
    {
        // This variable should be set to the allowed host from which your API can be accessed with
        $origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '';

        $response = $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
            ->withHeader(
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization',
            )
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0')
            ->withAddedHeader('Cache-Control', 'post-check=0, pre-check=0')
            ->withHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');

        if (ob_get_contents()) {
            ob_clean();
        }

        parent::emit($response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```php
->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```